# Is git rerere automatically invoked after second conflict in rebase?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When a rebase happens and git rerere is enabled, will it automatically be invoked after a second conflict that was previously resolved emerges or do I need to manually call git rerere? I'm asking this because I'd like to know whether GUIs like TortoiseGit support rerere. But this would only be the case if it is automaticaally invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseGit uses `cherry-pick` internally for implementing rebase. Therefore, `git rerere` is automatically invoked. However, even if conflicts are automatically resolved, the files are still marked as conflicted (you should not use "Edit conflict", but the options "Open" and "Resolved") as TortoiseGitMerge will not re-use the already resovled conflicts.

Comment: thanks for the advice, any idea what intellij uses for its rebase procedure?

Comment: I can only speak for TortoiseGit.

Comment: so the file will again be marked as a conflict but there will be no visible conflict in tortoise git?

Comment: In TortoiseGitMerge you will still see all conflicts as if rerere wasn't used.

Comment: Git rerere is no first class citizen in TortoiseGit - it's not claimed that it is supported. Just don't use TortoiseGitMerge when rerere automatically resolved conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

[git help rerere](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) states that `git rerere` is automatically called by both `git merge` and `git rebase`.

So yes, it must be called automatically on the second rebase conflict. By git. Not sure about TortoiseGit.